# My Arduino code will not compile, when I can't see anything wrong with it

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide

It keeps on giving me the error:

```
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560.
```

Other sketches work fine, but this one will not compile, even though I have all the libraries.

Here is the link for the code: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3R5NMiGZ3RPSk9WS0Y1amtEYms

The full error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.3 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_13'

libraries\IRLibRecv\IRLibRecv.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

d:/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega
2560.

This report would have more information with "Show verbose output during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. all i had to do was get rid of the tone() function.

Comment: ps. is there a way i could still use it?

Comment: Link is now dead, so your question is not of much use to others. This is why it is always best to include the code in the *question* and not a *link*. If the solution was to remove the `tone()` function, why don't you post that as an answer, explaining why that helped fix your code?

Comment: @Greenonline This thread is almost 2 years old...

Comment: There are questions on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest&page=2350) that are **10** years old which are *still* useful ... I came across your question whilst looking for a solution to an issue that I'm having, but it wasn't as useful as it *might* have been. That's all I'm saying... :-)

Comment: What do you need help with? I haven't used arduino for a while, but I might still be some help

Comment: It was a simple compile error, I have fixed it now, thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code besides the actual error:

- You are dividing an unsigned long by an integer which results in an unsigned long, then rounding it. Makes no sense.
- You are assigning (I assume - without seeing your code I can't be sure) long constants (eg `0xFFE01F`) to an integer - which overflows and whinges.

However your main problem is that you have two interrupt service routines (ISRs) for the same interrupt (vector 7). What that interrupt is I can't say, since it is different on different chips, and you don't seem able to make your mind up if you're using an Uno or a Mega (you tagged your question both for some reason). So you will have to change code and/or libraries to use different interrupts or combine the two together to use just one ISR.

Comment: should i change the int 'heldDown' to a long?

Comment: Yes. Better still, uint32_t.

Comment: what is uint32_t. ?

Comment: and how should i fix the vector errors?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see you code, but my guess is that you are passing an unsigned value into `round()`.

`millis()` returns an unsigned long, this means it can never be negative, so if you test `millis() >= 0` it will always be true.  That is your issue.

Write you own round function that doesn't check its greater than 0.

Comment: I don't think that's the error, it's just a warning. The real problem is in: (.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_7' (link error)

Answer (score 0):

just some warnings about generally unsafe/unsound code pieces.

the major issue (potentially unresolvable) is the vector-7 error. you should look into the datasheet to see what interrupt vector it is referring to first. There are more than one of such ISRs declared in your code.

Comment: how should i fix that

Answer (score 0):

I searched but couldn't find an answer, then I suddenly released my Arduino external power caused this problem. When I shut down the external power I could install it in my device. I hope it works for your problem.